# how to write string array index in ravendb

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

i have ravendb document called Orders like this

```
{
"MyOrders": [
    "S1",
    "S2"
],

"Id": "6666"
}
```

I will query this document and pass order string for example `S1`
Then it should return me that document as S1 matches it. I am pretty new to this ravendb. I am unable to find way. I have written only this so far

```
   public class MyOrderIndexes: AbstractIndexCreationTask<Order>
{

    public MyOrderIndexes()
    {
        Map = Orders => from Order in Orders
                                 select new
                                             {
                                                 ID= Order.Id
                                             };
        Index(x => x.Id, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
    }
}
```

can someone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query that, you don't need to create an index. Just do a query, Raven will create it for you.

This query should work just fine:

```
var hasS2 = session.Query<Orders>()
   .Where(o => o.MyOrders.Contains("S2"))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: So when we need to write index?

Comment: it complains that it cannot understand expression .Where(o => o.MyOrders.Any(myO => myO == "S2"))

Comment: Try use .Contains instead. I've updated the post with the code sample.

Comment: >> "When do we need to write an index?"

If you need special handling for fields at index time. For example, maybe you want to add spatial search data for a particular field, so that you can later search by geographic coordinates. Indexes are useful for such scenarios. But I recommend you let Raven handle indexes; my personal approach is, "Unless there's a special reason to write an index, don't. Let Raven handle it."

Comment: can you help me with index as i have pressure to write index and i am still struggling

Comment: Why do you need an index here?

Comment: Because i am told that we need indexes for whatever query we write and i dont have enough knowledge to overturn that decision

Comment: Run the above query. Raven will create an index automatically for it. Open Raven Studio and view the index (it should be named something like "Auto/Orders/ByMyOrders". You can copy/paste that index into your code.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the FieldIndexing on Id, and also that you need to map MyOrders to perform query on it.

Index:

```
public class MyOrderIndexes: AbstractIndexCreationTask<Order>
{    
    public MyOrderIndexes()
    {
        Map = Orders => from Order in Orders
                                 select new
                                 {
                                       Id = Order.Id,
                                       MyOrders = Order.MyOrders
                                 };
    }
}
```

Query:

```
var results = session
    .Query<Order, MyOrderIndexes>()
    .Where(x => x.MyOrders.Any(l => l == "S1"))
    .ToList();
```

Model:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> MyOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i have like this 
public List<string> MyOrders { get; private set; }

Comment: remove the `private`

Comment: what we acheive doing so and what is impact?

Comment: i'm not sure that RavenDB can set MyOrders with `private set`