# Creating an index in Ravendb that makes object array searchable

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

In Raven I am saving json documents, I wish to make an index that makes an object array in this json searchable.
An example from this is the following json structure.

```
"OrderProperties": [
    {
        "Key": "UserProfileType",
        "Value": "ClubMember"
    },
    {
        "Key": "FirstTimeReferer",
        "Value": "some value"
    }
]
```

I have tried to make an index that would work for it in raven studio. First I tried to do:

```
from doc in docs.WebOrderModels
select new {
    OrderProperties = doc.OrderProperties
}
```

Which did not work so I tried with the following

```
from doc in docs.WebOrderModels
select new {
    OrderProperties_Key = doc.OrderProperties.Key,
    OrderProperties_Value = doc.OrderProperties.Value,
}
```

However this still leaves the objects un-indexed so I cannot filter a search based on this.
Is there a way where I can create an index that makes the key, value pairs from json searchable?

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719711/how-to-write-string-array-index-in-ravendb

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer so that it might be able to help others.

The index I ended up creating looks like this:

```
from doc in docs.WebOrderModels
from prop in doc.OrderProperties
where prop.Key == "ShippingMethodAlias"
select new {
    Value = prop.Value
}
```

The where statement is there to reduce the fan out as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after [Dynamic fields](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/csharp/indexes/using-dynamic-fields) in index where the idea is to generate new custom index terms for dictionaries and nested structures.

For your example, the generated index terms (aka dynamic fields) would be:

```json
{
  "OrderProperties_UserProfileType": "ClubMember",
  "OrderProperties_FirstTimeReferer": "some value"
}
```

that can be accessed

- in `RQL` as `from index 'Y' where OrderProperties_UserProfileType = 'ClubMember'` (looks quite obvious),
- in `C#` as `s.Query<X,Y>().Where(p => p.OrderProperties["UserProfileType"].Equals("ClubMember"))` (use it as a dictionary).

Here is a blog post on the topic - [Power of Dynamic fields for indexing dictionaries and collections in RavenDB](https://alex-klaus.com/ravendb-yabt-dynamic-fields/). It has plenty of examples and you can find even more at [YABT project](https://github.com/ravendb/samples-yabt/) on GitHub.